# Single select with multiple radio-groups in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-group

I have two radio-groups with three options. In each group one option can be selected:

```
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default active">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>Radio1
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> Radio 4
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option5" autocomplete="off"> Radio 5
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option6" autocomplete="off"> Radio 6
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a possibility to allow only one selection over all options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `role="group"` and `data-toggle="buttons"` attributes from each individual group to a div which contains all the groups you want to share a selection.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
  <div class="hide-radio" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="btn-group-vertical">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked="">Radio1
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group-vertical">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> Radio 4
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option5" autocomplete="off"> Radio 5
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option6" autocomplete="off"> Radio 6
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you do this, you will need to add some CSS to replicate the way bootstrap hides the radio input (I used a new 'hide-radio' class).

CSS:

```
.hide-radio>.btn-group-vertical>.btn input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Live example: http://www.bootply.com/Suguq7eQNb

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the same `name` attribute to each radio, it will do what you except when clicking any of the radios, the checked one will uncheck itself.